# Are there guide how to build/run Play2 with Maven

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I would ask whether there is a workable guide on how to build/run play2 with maven. I want to use the latest of Play2 Framework, which is 2.6.1
I am surprised that Play2 Framewowrk doesn't provide official document on how work with Maven and Play2 together.

Comment: Don't be surprised, there is a whole world outside your Maven bubble! They chose a different tool for the job, and therefor naturally did not go out of their way to get it working in some other tool. There is, however, a [community maintained thing](https://play2-maven-plugin.github.io/play2-maven-plugin/index.html), maybe that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks @gpgekko for the helpful link, now I am able to setup the environment with Idea + Play2 + Maven